# Evaporation inside a container

Tags: thermodynamics, evaporation

This is for my engineering design project and our group needs to make a storage where humidity inside should be maintained above a certain range. So as a simple prototype, we simply added a bit of water in the container, let it evaporate, and measured rate of humidity change inside of it.

The question is, since we now want to generalize this concept to containers of any size/volume, it would be helpful to know the "formula" of evaporation inside a closed system (assume NO WIND). From the data we measured, it seems that the relationship between evaporation rate and time is logarithmic (which makes sense because it is approaching the saturation level). But we do not know of the effects of **temperature**, **volume** of the container, **amount of water** added in initially, and **initial humidity** inside the container on evaporation rate.

So in summary, I want to know the **equation of evaporation rate** inside a **closed** container **without wind**, if it exists. Links online that I've found refers to thermodynamics which I don't get much.

Comment: I believe *surface area* is more relevant than "volume"/"amount of water".

Comment: Are you aware (and understand) the Clausius–Clapeyron equation?

Comment: @user1583209 no I'm not aware of it. how can I apply it here? it seems relevant since it has to do with vapor pressure but I don't have much background knowledge on that.

Comment: @user1583209 and yes surface area is definitely more relevant since evaporation occurs at the surface of water

Comment: Are you actually interested in the time dependence of evaporation (in that case forget about Clausius-Clapeyron)  or in the equilibrium state (after waiting a while, when nothing is changing anymore).

Comment: Have you considered using dimensional analysis in the (basically) scale-up problem?  If you do, don't forget to include the diffusivity of water vapor in air as a parameter.  I assume the system is being treated as adiabatic?

Comment: If all you want is maintain certain minimum humidity inside the closed container, why do you need equation for evaporation *rate*? You need only the initial quantity of water to be placed inside the container to subsequently reach a certain level of humidity. This can be calculated indirectly using the Clausius-Clapeyron equation.